# How do I set the paper size in PrintPreviewDialog?

Tags: vb.net

For example =>

```
PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
PrintPreviewDialog1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
PrintPreviewDialog1.ClientSize = New Size(600, 600)
```

But i want the paper size?

Comment: thanks for edited Ken. it's my first post in this website. And sorry for my poor englisht.

Answer (score 1):

You set the paper size through the `PrintDocument` that you'll be previewing with the `PrintPreviewDialog`:

```
printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =  _
   printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[Index]
```

For more information, see the [`PaperSize` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.